# What's an antonym of virtuosity?

Tags: antonyms

Virtuosity intended as the ability of performing a difficult task and making it appear smooth and easy from the outside. 
So how would you define the inability of making something hard look very simple?

Comment: Are you sure that you have nailed down the definition of [virtuosity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/virtuosity?s=t)?

Comment: Do you mean the inability of making look so hard... or the ability of making look so hard.?

Comment: ***Virtuosity*** simply means *great skill* (usually, in music or another artistic pursuit). It has no special implication of "making it look easy" beyond what's pragmatically the likely context. So any synonym of ***incompetence*** would probably be a valid antonym, but the one to go for would depend on exact context.

Comment: Yep its about skill. But I dont believe it can be limited to artistic pursuit. On the other hand in any job you can find art :)

Comment: Incompetence looks far but would probably fit.

Comment: *Clumsiness*, *klutziness* come to mind (the latter is usually only used facetiously).

Comment: Do all words have opposites? This repeated request for antonyms on the site suggests that some people think that language operates in a symmetrical universe -rather like mathematics. Besides many a good dictionary/thesaurus will suggest possible synonyms and antonyms.

Comment: @WS2 But opposites are so attractive.

Comment: I wasn't looking exactly for an antonym.  But precisely I used an antonym to describe the scenario. Clumsy is the most appropriate IMHO

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True of magnetism, but of very little else, in my opinion.

Comment: @koalaok- *Clumsy* would seem to imply an inability to perform a task at all.  It seems that your questions asks about someone who can perform the task perfectly well but does not have the ability to make it look easy while doing it- perhaps they lack flair or style.

Comment: What about "laboriousness" ? Where "laborious" means *characterized by or exhibiting excessive effort, dullness, and lack of spontaneity*.

Comment: I'm thinking laboriousness and awkwardness are both eligible. maybe the first one in a more serious environment, the second more likely when it comes to be funny strange.

Answer (score 2):

*awkwardness*

lacking skill or dexterity, lacking grace or ease in movement, not well planned or designed for easy or effective use (dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [*maladroitness*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maladroitness) is the word you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Brendan, please provide references when you post an answer.